# Deploy war based on runtime property in Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I want to deploy an EAR in weblogic and that EAR can contain a WAR based on a property from properties file. If property is set to true then deploy the war otherwise not.

How can i restrict war deployement based on property in weblogic 12c ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a wlst script and a deployment plan. You will have to deploy your ear with the wlst deploy command. Your ear should always contains the war module. Prepare 2 versions of the deployment plan : one will add the war module into the application.xml file, the other one will not. Write a wlst script that will read your property file and deploy the application with the corresponding deployment plan.
We can imagine also to update the ear to update the application.xml file with a wlst script before deploying it.